# Excel & VBA: sum hourly info into days, then find highest day value

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have data in the form of 1 1 1 (1st hour of January first) through 12 31 24 (last hour of December 31). I'm trying sum the usage on a daily basis (the 24 hours associated with each day), and then find the largest consumption of all the days in a year. Trying to make a macro in excel using VBA

```
1   1   1   0.011
```

where Column A is month, Column B is day, Column C is hour and Column D is usage

EDIT: then, if possible, indicate which date has the has usage?

Comment: The last hour should be 23, not 24. Midnight to 01:00 am is considered 0 hour.

Comment: It looks like midnight starts at 1 hour

Comment: You need a helper column that add up each day's usage on the last hour of the day then take the MAX of that column and use INDEX to find the date.

Comment: Not sure how to do that...

Comment: ended up using a pivot table... but i want something that will update when the file changes, and not have to create a pivot table every time

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution: This assumes that your first row is headings, and the data starts row 2.

Sub getUsage()

```
Dim lim As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim total As Double
Dim rVal As range

total = 0
Final = 0

lim = Sheet1.range("B2", Sheet1.range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

For count = 0 To lim

   total = total + Sheet1.range("B2").Offset(count, 2).Value
   If Sheet1.range("B2").Offset(count, 1) = 1 Then
        If total > Final Then
            Final = total
            Set rVal = Sheet1.range("B2").Offset(count, 0)
        End If
        total = 0
   End If

Next

MsgBox ("The date with the largest usage is: " & rVal.Offset(0, -1) & ", " & rVal.Offset(0, 0) & ", " & rVal.Offset(0, 1))
```

End Sub

Comment: Getting run time error 91 the rVal= Sheet.Range("B2").Offset (count, 0);;; getting error "object variable or with not variable not set"

Comment: Thanks for the help, I don't think it's working properly. I ran it and it said the largest day was 12 31 1 and I changed 1 1 1 to be 10,000, and same result :( Would it help if I shared document?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.

Comment: You may need to zero total after Final = total or you just keep building it up.

Answer (score 0):

This User Defined Function¹ processes your block of data in-memory and returns the maximum daily usage as well as the date it occurred on.

```
Function fcnDatedMax(rng As Range, Optional yr As Integer = 2015)
    Dim u As Long, vUSEs As Variant, dbl As Double

    With rng
        vUSEs = .Resize(.Rows.Count + 1, .Columns.Count).Value2
        For u = 1 To 4
            vUSEs(UBound(vUSEs, 1), u) = vUSEs(LBound(vUSEs, 1), u)
        Next u
        dbl = vUSEs(UBound(vUSEs, 1), UBound(vUSEs, 2))
    End With

    For u = LBound(vUSEs, 1) + 1 To UBound(vUSEs, 1) - 1
        If vUSEs(u, 2) <> vUSEs(u - 1, 2) Then
            If dbl > vUSEs(UBound(vUSEs, 1), UBound(vUSEs, 2)) Then
                vUSEs(UBound(vUSEs, 1), 1) = vUSEs(u - 1, 1)
                vUSEs(UBound(vUSEs, 1), 2) = vUSEs(u - 1, 2)
                vUSEs(UBound(vUSEs, 1), 3) = vUSEs(u - 1, 3)
                vUSEs(UBound(vUSEs, 1), 4) = dbl
            End If
            dbl = vUSEs(u, UBound(vUSEs, 2))
        Else
            dbl = dbl + vUSEs(u, UBound(vUSEs, 2))
        End If
    Next u

    fcnDatedMax = Format(DateSerial(yr, vUSEs(UBound(vUSEs, 1), 1), vUSEs(UBound(vUSEs, 1), 2)), "dd-mmm-yyyy ") & _
                  vUSEs(UBound(vUSEs, 1), UBound(vUSEs, 2))
    Erase vUSEs
End Function
```

In G145 and H145 as,

```
=MAX(E:E)
=fcnDatedMax(A2:D2161)
```

This ran through the first quarter of the year and returned the correct daily maximum as well as the date it occurred on.

[image]

---

¹ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>